# How do I get two selectboxes to work in reverse in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How do I get two selectboxes to work in reverse in angularjs?
I have this example.

```
<select id="srcCurrency" ng-model="params.srcCurrency">                     
    <option>USD</option>
    <option>KRW</option>
</select>
<select id="dstCurrency" ng-model="params.dstCurrency">
   <option >USD/option>
   <option >KRW</option>
</select>
```

I want to choose opposite to each other.
I have this example but I want a more efficient way.

```
$scope.$watch('params.srcCurrency', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  if ($scope.params.srcCurrency == "USD") {
    $scope.params.dstCurrency = "KRW";
  } else {
    $scope.params.dstCurrency = "USD";
  }

}, true);

$scope.$watch('params.dstCurrency', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  if ($scope.params.dstCurrency == "USD") {
    $scope.params.srcCurrency = "KRW";
  } else {
    $scope.params.srcCurrency = "USD";
  }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="srcCurrency" ng-model="params.srcCurrency" ng-change="switchCurrencies(params.srcCurrency, 'source')">                     
    <option>USD</option>
    <option>KRW</option>
</select>
<select id="dstCurrency" ng-model="params.dstCurrency" ng-change="switchCurrencies(params.dstCurrency, 'dest')">
   <option >USD/option>
   <option >KRW</option>
</select>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.switchCurrencies = function(resource, type){
  if(type == 'source'){
    $scope.params.dstCurrency = angular.copy(resource);
  }else{
    $scope.params.srcCurrency = angular.copy(resource);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is because the srcCurrency value has already been changed and the select value is the same.

Comment: When you change srcCurrency, the last value is stored in $scope.params.srcCurrency and you can assign this value to $scope.params.dstCurrency. did it work ?

Comment: It did not work. and 
The last value was not stored in $ scope.params.srcCurrency.
The value of $ scope.params.srcCurrency is changed by ng-model at the moment of change.

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not work.
The resource is also no different from the value of ng-model.

Comment: thank you for you information. I resolved problem . by using {{ }}

like this ng-change="switchCurrencies('{{params.srcCurrency}}', 'source')"

Answer (score 0):

You better to avoid using $watch. Instead of use ng-change

Comment: What is the reason?

Comment: Avoiding watch is one of best practice.$Watch effects the performance application. Because they must be re-evaluated with each run of the $digest loop.  When the value being observed by the watch changes, the function registered with the watch executes synchronously, blocking the web browser user interface temporarily. For watches that run extremely quickly, the locking is not noticeable. However, for watches that do a significant amount of processing, a noticeable slowdown in an AngularJS application can occur.